# Does the latest transaction in a Braintree Subscription object appear at the top of the array or bottom?

Tags: braintree

I am having a hard time deciphering the the Subscription Object for Braintree that is returned via a web-hook upon each billing cycle.

The Braintree documentation fails to shed light upon the nature of transactions which are supposed to appear in the transaction array.

For example, will the latest transaction appear at the bottom of the array, or at the top. I need to know this so I may record the appropriate data in my CRM.

```
<transactions type="array">
 <transaction> First Payment </transaction>
</transactions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions about integrating with Braintree, your best bet is to [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/). I've told the docs team about the missing info, and it should be fixed soon. Thanks for the report!</sub>

Braintree serializes subscription transactions newest-first, but it's not documented. You can always make sure by looking at the [`created_at`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/reference/response/transaction#created_at) or [`updated_at`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/reference/response/transaction#updated_at) dates on the transactions.

Comment: Thanks, so `response->subject['subscription']['transactions'][0]; ` will always yield the latest transaction for a particular subscription. Correct? If yes, any way to test this out without waiting for 1 day on production, and even better, on Sandbox?

Comment: @AliGajani Yes, that's correct, though you should be using the client library instead of looking at the raw response. If you have more questions about testing, you should contact the Braintree support team.

Comment: @agr: Does Braintree support getting a list of subscription ids given query parameters? Like a bulk list API, so that I can do things instead of doing it by hand.